# Android: Setting ID's for Array of Image Buttons

Tags: android, for-loop, onclick, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I am making an android application that allows users to click either a plus or minus image button to change the number displayed in a text view.

There are 18 of the text views and a plus and minus image button for each text view.

The activity crashes when i get to this activity, it is because of this section of code. I have been unable to produce any helpful information when debugging the code so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**At the top of my activity:**

```
int score = 0;
ImageButton addButtons[] = {(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole1Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole2Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole3Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole4Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole5Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole6Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole7Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole8Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole9Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole10Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole11Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole12Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole13Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole14Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole15Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole16Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole17Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole18Up),};
ImageButton minusButtons[] = {(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole1Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole2Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole3Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole4Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole5Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole6Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole7Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole8Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole9Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole10Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole11Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole12Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole13Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole14Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole15Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole16Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole17Down), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole18Down),};
int[] scoreIDs = new int[] {R.id.score1, R.id.score2, R.id.score3, R.id.score4, R.id.score5, R.id.score6, R.id.score7, R.id.score8, R.id.score9, R.id.score10, R.id.score11, R.id.score12, R.id.score13, R.id.score14, R.id.score15, R.id.score16, R.id.score17, R.id.score18,};

public void setPlusButtons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < addButtons.length; i++)
    {
        final int j = i;
        ImageButton button = addButtons[i];

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(scoreIDs[j]);
                tv5.setText(score++);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setMinusButtons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < minusButtons.length; i++)
    {
        final int j = i;
        ImageButton button = minusButtons[i];

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(scoreIDs[j]);
                tv5.setText(score--);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My onCreate:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        chosenCourseValue = extras.getString("passedChosenCourse");
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            AsyncAPI APIThread = new AsyncAPI();
            APIThread.execute();
    setPlusButtons();
    setMinusButtons();
}
```

**Section of my Activity XML**

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Holes"
            android:id="@+id/hole1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:height="45dp"
            android:width="45dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pars"
            android:id="@+id/hole1Par"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score"
            android:id="@+id/score1"
            android:paddingLeft="42dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:id="@+id/hole1Up"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            android:background="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:id="@+id/hole1Down"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/minus"
            android:background="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was unable to get an error through debugging, so was hoping someone would be able to point out what I am doing wrong with my code, see paragraph three.

Comment: Hey OJJ, I think, instead of doing like this,you could use `ListView or RecylerView` with cutstom layout and adapter.

Comment: Can you post `activity_course` xml layout file? I have basic idea to reduce code and complexity of your code.

Comment: Hi user370305, I've added a section of the xml layout in question (couldn't upload all because of word limit). Basically there are 18 of these wrapped in a linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. Good Now just go with stepwise one by one.

**Step 1:** define views like, as we include `android:onClick` and `android:tag` properties in views.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Score"
        android:id="@+id/score1"
        android:paddingLeft="42dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/hole1Up"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:onClick="upButtonOnClick" // We defines up button's onclick in xml
        android:tag="score1"/> // associated TextView id is in Tag of image button

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/hole1Down"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/minus"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:onClick="downButtonOnClick" // We defines down button's onclick in xml
        android:tag="score1"/> // associated TextView id is in Tag of image button
```

So all up image buttons should have declared `android:onClick="upButtonOnClick"` and all down image buttons should have declared `android:onClick="downButtonOnClick"` with associate TextView ID as `android:tag` property.

**Step 2:**

Instead of `setPlusButtons()` and `setMinusButtons()` define `upButtonOnClick()` and `downButtonOnClick()` like,

```
public void upButtonOnClick(View imageButton)
{
          int textViewId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageButton.getTag(), "id", getPackageName());
          TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
          score.setText(score++);
}
```

And

```
public void downButtonOnClick(View imageButton)
{
          int textViewId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageButton.getTag(), "id", getPackageName());
          TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
          score.setText(score--);
}
```

That's it. you don't need to declare array of ImageButtons, TextView's Id and again don't need to set on click listener to all image buttons.

**Note:** be sure ImageButton Tag should be same as associated TextView ID.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` will only return a View after the layout has been set. Your code right now assigns `null` values to your `ImageButton` arrays, so when you loop through them and try to set click listeners, you get a NPE crash.

That means you will have to settle for your `ImageButton[]` to be a declaration, and then initialize its values in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()` has been called.

```
ImageButton addButtons[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);

    addButtons = new ImageButton[]{(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole1Up), (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hole2Up)};
    setPlusButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just an example to how can you set the ids of a group of buttons :

```
Button [] buttens=new Button[5];
final int ID= R.id.bChoice1;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        button[i]=(Button)findViewById(ID+i);
    }
```

but be careful it works as long as you set your button id's consecutively !